# PHP - get total number of array items with a specific number sequence in value

Tags: php

So, basically I'm trying to count the number of landline phone numbers in a list of both landlines and mobile phone numbers $mobile_list (071234567890,02039989435,0781...)

```
$mobile_array = explode(",",$mobile_list);        // turn into an array
$landlines = array_count_values($mobile_array);  // create count variable
echo $landlines["020..."];                      // print the number of numbers
```

So, I get the basic count specific elements function, but I don't see where I can specify if an element 'starts with' or 'contains' a sequence. With the above you can only specify an exact phone number (obviously not useful).

Any help would be great!

Comment: so you actually need to find the item(s) that contain specific number sequence and count how many of them are?

Comment: Trying to count the number of landline numbers in the string and ignore mobile numbers, so ignore numbers starting with 07... and count numbers starting with 020...

Comment: Do you need to count all values that start with sequence, or you want to count values that both - start with or contain the sequence?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `array_filter()` or `preg_grep()` functions to find all numbers that contain or starts with given number sequence.

**Note**: There is easier and better solution in other answers that cover request to find values that start with given number sequence. 
Because you have mentioned -  "but I don't see where I can specify if an element 'starts with' or 'contains' a sequence." - My code assumes that you wan't to find any occurrence of sequence, not only in start of string of each item.

```
$mobile_list = '02000, 02032435, 039002300, 00305600';
$mobile_array = explode(",",$mobile_list);        // turn into an array
$landlines = array_count_values($mobile_array);  // create count variable
$sequence = '020';                      // print the number of numbers



function filter_phone_numbers($mobile_array, $sequence){
    return array_filter($mobile_array, function ($item) use ($sequence) {
        if (stripos($item, $sequence) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}

$filtered_items = array_unique (filter_phone_numbers($mobile_array, $sequence)); //use array_unique in case we find same number that both contains or starts with sequence

echo count($filtered_items);
```

Or with `preg_grep()`:

```
$mobile_list = '02000, 02032435, 039002300, 00305600';
$mobile_array = explode(",",$mobile_list);        // turn into an array
$landlines = array_count_values($mobile_array);  // create count variable
$sequence = preg_quote('020', '~'); ;                      // print the number of numbers



function grep_phone_numbers($mobile_array, $sequence){

     return preg_grep('~' . $sequence . '~', $mobile_array);

}
//use array_unique in case we find same number that both contains or starts with sequence
$filtered_items = array_unique(grep_phone_numbers($mobile_array, $sequence));

echo count($filtered_items);
```

Comment: While not wrong, these are fairly heavy actions to perform. Also, this code wil also match strings containing the string, not just 'beginning with', e.g.: `123020`

Comment: Define 'heavy'? Do you mean it'll use a lot of computing power? My list is over 1,000 phone numbers long...

Comment: "but I don't see where I can specify if an element 'starts with' or 'contains' a sequence. " . This is the reason I used this, instead of substr, or specific regex.  He can just modify stripos that checks if starts with, if returns position od 0, or regular expression use with ^ to check if starts with sequence. @Martijn

Comment: also, preg_grep is much more easier to perform, than array_reduce

Comment: @NathanWinch, that is not large number of items, it should be fair fast

Comment: `preg_grep is much more easier to perform, than array_reduce`. Please provide a source for this. I'm not confinced that a regex based function is faster then basically a for loop.

Comment: @Martijn, for same goal results, I get with preg_grep twice faster than with array_reduce or array_filter

Comment: That still is not a source. There are online benchmarks, it could be that your code is (unintentially) biased.

Comment: @Martijn, I don't have a reason to bias my code :). preg_grep in this case is faster,  while calling a user function within array_reduce iteration, preg_grep returns items that match the pattern on using regular expression, without user based code. I agree that it should be avoided over usage of PCRE functions. This is specific case.

Comment: I think the elephant in the room is why is your code outputting 1 instead of 2? https://3v4l.org/ofs8H

Comment: Here is a benchmark for my `array_reduce()` solution processing 1000 numbers split 50/50 starting with `020` or `07` https://3v4l.org/XF6E6/perf#output. I'm not concerned about it's performance. I'll try to add the string explode though, missed that bit.

Comment: Here is a test that explodes the string first: https://3v4l.org/UEDqp/perf#output It'd be good to see how all the solutions stack up. PHP: 7.3, SystemTime: 0.017, UserTime: 0.005, Memory: 10.94.

Comment: @Sarcoma use microtime instead. 3v4l's performance tab is not even close to correct

Comment: @Sarcoma a small scale version is posted in my answer at the bottom

Comment: @Andreas Nice, I've combined that with the my list of 1000 numbers to make the differences more pronounced. You are hands down the winner, I can live with second place :) https://3v4l.org/8bntce

Comment: @Andreas, 'I think the elephant in the room is why is your code outputting 1 instead of 2?' - It was typo, missing `!== false` in conditional

Comment: Also, both solutions refer to question that values that contain or start with sequence need to be count in. Not just start with. I have also considered 
`substr()` as part of a solution.

Comment: You are wrong @niklaz read the question again. OP asks for starts with.

Comment: @Andreas, "but I don't see where I can specify if an element 'starts with' or 'contains' a sequence."  - We can go in a loop for hours :) But I think it is very clear what is written :)

Comment: Yes also written is this: `so ignore numbers starting with 07... and count numbers starting with 020...`

Comment: @Sarcoma note that my explode code actually is not complete. Op said in comment to my answer that the total count of numbers is also of interest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176522/discussion-between-niklaz-and-andreas).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_reduce()` to count the occurrences of strings beginning with `'020'`

```
$mobile_list = "02039619491,07143502893,02088024526,07351261813,02095694897";
$mobile_array = explode(',', $mobile_list);

function landlineCount($carry, $item)
{
    if (substr($item, 0, 3) === '020') {
        return $carry += 1;
    }

    return $carry;
}


$count = array_reduce($mobile_array, 'landlineCount');

echo $count;
```

prints `3`

---

I'm sure the OP has finished what they needed to do hours ago but for fun here is a faster way to count the landlines.

I hadn't spotted that the question original code was exploding the string.

That isn't necessary, you can just count the sub strings with `substr_count()` this could miss the first which wouldn't have a comma before it so I check for that too with `substr()`.

If you need the total count of all numbers you can just count the commas with `substr_count()` again and add one.

```
$count = substr($mobile_list, 0, 3) === '020' ? 1 : 0;
$count += substr_count($mobile_list, ",020");
$totalCount = substr_count($mobile_list, ",") + 1;

echo $count;
echo $totalCount;
```

Here is the bench run a 1000 times to get an average.

https://3v4l.org/Sma66

Comment: Like the substr_count version. Very nice way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks, I twigged on to it after I saw your `explode(',020', $mobile_list)` idea.

Comment: Yeah I see where you got the idea from and it's a nice contribution. What is the performance of it compared to a explode version? Meaning one explode on comma only to get total and one comma020

Comment: It's about 10x faster than my explode + reduce method. I'm not sure I follow your question.

Comment: Bench is at the bottom

Comment: For me exploding a string only makes sense if the resulting array is something that is usable. So either explode on the commas or not at all.

Comment: I agree, this is what I meant. By some reason your shows 1. But either way it's much faster than mine. https://3v4l.org/fu7HA

Comment: Missing a space, I used a different list with no space after the comma. Here is the updated test: https://3v4l.org/LodC7

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any reason to first explode the string to an array, and then check each array item.
That is a complete waste of performance!

I suggest using preg_match_all and match with word boundary "020".
That means the "word" has to start with 020.

```
$mobile_list = "071234567890,02039989435,0781,020122,123020";

preg_match_all("/\b020\d+\b/", $mobile_list, $m);
var_dump($m);
echo count($m[0]); // 2
```

https://3v4l.org/ucSDm

---

---

The lightest and fastest method I have found is to explode on ",020".
The array that is returned has item 0 as undefined, meaning we don't know if it's a 020 number so I have to look at that manually.

```
$temp = explode(",020", $mobile_list);
$cnt = count($temp);
if(substr($temp[0],0,3) != "020") $cnt--;
echo $cnt;
```

A small scale test shows this as the fastest method.
https://3v4l.org/rD54d

Comment: I exploded the string because I also need to count the total number of numbers as well as filter them. I guess there is an easy way to do this as well using this method?

Comment: And what about finding values that contain the sequence, not start with?

Comment: @niklaz that is not the question. The question is starts with. OP asked a question "I don't know how to create a code that makes difference of starts with and contains". So you can remove the downvote.

Comment: @Andreas, I will remove downvote, since I actually didn't want to downvote, but need to wait for a 12 minute or less. But you need to read carefully again :) 
"I can specify if an element 'starts with' or 'contains' a sequence. "  

Starts with or contains :)

Comment: You don't think that is a typo for *"I can**t** specify if an element 'starts with' or 'contains' a sequence. "*

Comment: @Andreas, no, typo would be missing a part of sentence, wrongly spelled word. Why would he anyway put 'or contains' if he didn't wanted to? Anyway, I think my answer fulfills request according to such context. I don't care, down vote it as much as you like. I don't like what SO has become.

Comment: @Sarcoma as I said, I really liked the solution! I have no problem upvoting competition answers or even awarding bounty's to them if they are good

Comment: I also thought of a better way to count the total numbers today, `$totalCount  = (strlen($mobile_list) + 1) / 12;` shaved a few nano seconds off lol.

Comment: @Sarcoma not sure I understand how that counts the numbers. Strlen returns the lenght of a string

Comment: Yes, if the telephone numbers are all the same length you just divided the (string length + 1) by (number length plus the comma).

Comment: Ok I see, but I don't think you can assume all phone numbers are 12 digits. But maybe you can count the commas

Answer (score -2):

I recommend doing this with the database. The database is design to manage data and can do it a lot more efficient than PHP can. You can simply put it into a query and just get the result you want in 1 go:

```
SELECT * FROM phone_numbers WHERE number LIKE '020%'
```

If you get the data from the database anyways, that LIKE adds a little time to the query, but less that it takes PHP to loop, strpos and store the results. Also, as you return a smaller dataset, less resources are being used.

Comment: Why do you assume that he uses mySQL database to retrieve the data?

Comment: Well, because few people have code running on a piece of paper :) But i've rephrased 'I assume' :)

Comment: To the downvotes, please explain why? IMO nothing in this answer is incorrect, a database would be better suited for the task, even if he hasn't got one now :)

Comment: I removed my downvote. And about MySQL,  he might get data from csv, json output, external service in any other format, yaml, plaintext, you don't know that :)  
So your "coding on a piece of paper" joke is funny, but not good argument and not in a good context :)